# Can I use other options then the In-App Option to sell things in iOS?

Tags: html, ios, css

I only would like to know if I can use other options then in-app buys in my iOS apps or is this restricted by Apple? I would like to include CreditCard and transfer directly into my app.

Restricted or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are selling digital goods, like upgrade, audio, books, ect.. you will have to use Apple's in-app purchases.

If you are selling physical goods, like clothes, pizza ect..  you can not use Apple's in-app purchases but should provide your own.

So it is up to what you are selling in you app.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would like to sell a video coaching (think this is digital). A User can upload his video on my server and send it to me (he has to pay money for that) and i would like to offer him the option to pay with transfer or inapp-buy. But if i understood your answer right, it is not possible?!

Comment: You are correct, these kind of purchases can only be done with an In-App purchase.